# What data structure should I use to define states at 3600 points?

Tags: python

I am working on a personal project that analyzes hockey player shot data. One thing that I would like to investigate is the effects of different game-states (5v5, power play, short handed).  The problem that I have is that I am not sure how to structure this part of my program.

My initial thought is to define a dictionary with 3600 sub-dictionaries as follows:

```
game_state = {}
game_state[time] = {}
game_state[time][home] = []
game_state[time][away] = []
```

I can then use the time for each shot event that I am interested in to lookup each teams' game-state.  This, however, seems like an inefficient way of doing things.

As I am writing this question up it occurs to me that most of the game is 5v5 for both teams.  Perhaps I could set up a similar dictionary but only use the times that the game-state is not 5v5 to generate the keys, and then when looking up play data assume that no entry means a 5v5 game-state.

**My Question**: Is there something better suited than a dictionary for this kind of application?

##### Edit:

To @Karl Knechtel's point, I do not need to save any of this information beyond one iteration of a for loop in my main file.  In the main file I loop through `game_data` (a pickled JSON file) and collect x, y coordinates for all shots to later be binned and plotted.  I am trying to refine the shot data to consider only a specific game state by introducing an additional check into my data parsing loop.

Comment: Any time you're tempted to design a dictionary with 3600 sub dictionaries... don't.  Nobody has *that* much ram.. well alright you probably do, but there's no need to show off.  What about a database, with caching? Or a large numpy array? :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We can't give specific help for this because you don't yet have a defined *problem to solve*. Please read [ask] and keep in mind that this is *not a discussion forum*. But here's my advice: "One things that I would like to investigate is the effects of different gamestates (5v5, power play, short handed)." Do you actually need to consider every possible combination (really a cartesian product) of these aspects of the game state? Do you actually need to **store information** about them? What actual *task are you trying to perform* this way?

Comment: Incidentally for UK readers, I had to read this three times before I remembered *ice* hockey

Comment: @2e0byo - I'll look into a numpy array... seems like that could be an option.  Thanks!

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I do not need to save any data beyond on iteration of a for loop.  I edited the main post and hope I have clarified sufficiently.

Comment: @2e0byo I mean, that really wouldn't require a lot of memory.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga some of us still have our 486s!  8MB is enough for anyone!  But yes, it was a tongue-in-cheek comment, more about the fact that massive nested hashtables are probably not what you want.  FWIW a repl after running `a = {k: {f"key{k}": f"val{k}" * 120} for k in range(3600)` takes nearly a whole 2.2MB of virtual memory (up a *whole MB* from before I ran the comprehension).  Which is ofc 20% of the ram on my poor 486. If you're storing every bit of gameplay---which I initially thought---it would likely be a lot larger, but still trivial on a modern system.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the perfect use case for a relational database like SQLite or Postgres. Without getting too much into the nitty gritties, you could define a relation called `Shot` with `time` as a primary key. This would allow you to also look up more interesting questions like "How many shots are made short handed when it's a powerplay?" You could potentially also have a relation called `Game` which allows you to know which shots happened in which game.

If you want a less labor intensive solution, I think grouping the data into a class would be good idea. For example,

```py
class Shot:
    def __init__(self, time: int, short_hand: bool, num_players: int):
        self.time = time
        self.short_hand = short_hand
        self.num_players = num_players
```

You could then have a dictionary that maps time to `Shot` instances.

```py
shots: dict[int, Shot] = {}
shots[100] = Shot(100, False, 10)
shots[150] = Shot(150, True, 9)
...
```

NB: I *highly* suggest the first option since it sounds like it will be more useful for your case.

Comment: You make a good point.  My end goal is to build a GSVA model and I'm already starting to see that execution time and memory usage are going to be a problem as I try to scale this up to teams instead of individual players.  This data also isn't changing so a database that I pull info from into Python makes a tonne of sense.